# Formulae with multiple values

Tags: python

You are given these formulae:

```
formula(1,[d,g],h)
formula(2,[f,h],i)
formula(3,[a,d],f)     
formula(4,[b,c],a)
```

Find the list L of formulae to find f given c, b, d.

A little explanation:
Each formula has an index as the first item in the parentheses.
The values in the square brackets represent the value you need to know in order to obtain the last item in the parentheses.

The solution to this particular problem is: L = [4,3]
The values you have in the beginning are: c, b, d
After applying formula 4 (which requires [b,c] and you have both of them) you have:   c, b, d, a (since a is the "output" of formula 4)
Then you repeat the same for formula 3 and you get the value f as an output, solving the problem.

Let me draw a simple diagram explaining the situation better:

```
-  /  |  c, b, d 

-  4  |  c, b, d, a

-  3  |  c, b, d, a, f
```

Therefore L = [4, 3]

On the right side you can see the values we know after applying each formula, while on the left there are the formulae we have used.

I was trying to code a solver for this kind of problem in python, but it came out to be a pretty difficult task, so... StackOverflow I choose you!

Do not esitate to contact me for further information.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)! Your formulae are describing dependencies. For example formulae(3, [a,d], f) means f depends-on a & d. which translated to `a -> f` & `d -> f`. The other formulae are also parts of this graph.

You have been given some known source-nodes in the graph(b,c,d). And a target-node(f).

What you need to do is do a graph-search from any of the known nodes until you reach the target node. You can do this with Depth-first search, breadth-first search etc. See: https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/grids/graphs.html